# How to correctly set Zip Code Ranges with WooCommerce Shipping Zones?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to include all US locations except Alaska & Hawaii. It says that zip code ranges are supported by entering a ... between the zip codes.

However the zip code I am entering 90XXX-XXXX is not allowing free shipping.

WC 3.1.2
WP 4.8.1

[image]

Comment: Realized that Washington State jumps out of the Continental US range (http://www.structnet.com/instructions/zip_min_max_by_state.html), so the range would need to be modified from what is shown in the screenshot. Would be easier just to create a separate zone for Hawaii and Alaska.

Answer (score 1):

The Zip Code that I was testing with had a dash in it, for example 90XXX-XXXX and it wasn't allowing free shipping. I found that you need to enter the Zip Code ranges with and without the dash in order for the coupon to be applied when a zip code is entered with or without a dash.

The following is now working when I enter zip code 90XXX or 90XXX-XXXX:

[image: screenshot of shipping zones set up for zip code ranges]

Answer (score 0):

Use this example:
Ex 71331*...73491*